# Convertir string a array php

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente consulta, como puedo convertir directamente en un array php el siguiente string **"{valor1,valor2,valor3,valor4}"** este string me lo genera una consulta array en postgresql, y necesito mostrar esos datos en forma de lista en html

Comment: viene entre llaves? lo suyo  (si fuera un json) seria devolverlo entre corchetes y con comillas... asi de primeras seria quitar las {} con trim y luego un explode de esa cadena sin las llaves...

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Qué has intentado? Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar un [mcve]. En cuanto a tu duda, podrías eliminar las llaves que delimitan tu cadena, y luego usar [`explode`](http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/es/function.explode.php). Saludos

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de Postgresql? [En Postgresql existen funciones avanzadas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html) para obtener los datos sin tener que manipularlos luego con `explode`,  creando un json por ejemplo con `json_decode`. Esto es particularmente útil en resultados complejos o que están destinados a ser mapeados en una clase de tu modelo de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para convertir un string a un array en php, puedes utilizar la funcion `explode()`.

Esto te puede servir.

```
    //Este es tu string original
       $string = "{valor1,valor2,valor3,valor4}";


    //Creas un nuevo string removiendo los corchetes para que no 
    //queden en to arreglo, para eso puedes usar la funcion trim()
      $nuevoString = trim($string,"{ }");
    // Quedara asi: valor1,valor2,valor3,valor4


   
    //Ahora llamas a la funcion explode en tu string ya formateado
      $arreglo = explode(",",$nuevoString);

    //Tu array quedara asi: 
    //[0] => valor1 [1] => valor2 [2] => valor3 [3] => valor4
```

Como puedes ver la funcion explode() devuelve un arreglo numerico, no asociativo.